# Ternary operator results in undefined useState after first render

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on my first React.js project and am trying to build a primitive version of a personal website. I am running into an issue with the dropdown function of the burger-style sidebar - I want to use onClick to show and hide the Navbar links. I am trying to do this by giving my className for my Navbar (.nav_links in my code) an ID which will change from "hidden" to "show" using the showLinks hook and also using the ternary operator. However, the initial value after ternary operator in div is set to undefined after the first render, and so my onClick method does not work. I would appreciate any clarity on this issue as none of the other stackoverflow posts seem directly relevant to my methods of writing the website.

Here are parts of my code for reference:

```
const [showLinks, setShowLinks] = useState(true);


    <nav>
        <ul className="nav_links" id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Resume</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a className="contact_form" href="#"><button>Contact Me</button></a>
    <div className="burger" onClick={() => setShowLinks(!showLinks)}>
            <div className="line1"></div>
            <div className="line2"></div>
            <div className="line3"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Parts of my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 843px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .nav_links #hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav_links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 20vh;
        top: 20vh;
        background-color: ghostwhite;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here  `.nav_links #hidden` you're hiding a `#hidden` that's inside a `.nav_links`

Comment: My idea was to have either the .nav_links with or without #hidden be used based on what the showLinks was set to. The issue for me is the id in that first line <nav id is set to undefined... print statements confirmed that for me in the console.

Comment: Try changing your selector to `#hidden .nav_links`, because currently `display: none` is never applied, since `#hidden` is not inside an element with a `.nav_links` regardless of the `showLinks` value.

Comment: Just edited it to have the id by the nav_links instead since that is what I have in my code at the moment. Still does not work. I have: onClick={console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("nav_links").id)} besides my .burger class and lines, and it is printing undefined everytime I click on the burger lines.

Comment: @EmilDimitrov beat me to it. He pointed out the selector ordering problem while I was typing my answer. :)

Comment: @chocolatecroissant another issue with your markup is having a `<button>` nested inside an `<a>` tag. That's not W3C valid markup. You should make it one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the error described based on your code snippets.

Here's a working Code Sandbox with what you have so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-leaf-gm7pz

One issue I noticed was the ordering of your `#hidden` selector. You had this:

```css
.nav_links #hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

However, in your markup, you were nesting those elements like this:

```html
<nav id="hidden">
  <ul className="nav_links">
  ...
```

So as-is, that wouldn't work since you have the nesting order switched. I changed the css to this:

```css
#hidden .nav_links {
  display: none;
}
```

I also added a placeholder style for your `.burger` class in [`Styles.css`](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-leaf-gm7pz?file=/src/styles.css) so it would be visible in the working codesandbox example.

The result (once user resizes viewport to to mobile width) toggles your menu state without any console errors. Can't say it's exactly what you're after without more context. If it doesn't fix your problem, I'd suggest trying to post an updated codesandbox with a working example (while keeping it [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so we can see precisely what's failing.

---

Side note, I'd recommend using a `class` on your `<nav>` element for visual state instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

just use ternary operator before ul tag like this

```
<nav>
    {(showLinks)?
    <ul className="nav_links" >
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Resume</li>
    </ul>
    : null}
</nav>
```

Comment: You could also do this: `<nav>{showLinks && (<ul>...</ul>)}</nav>`

Answer (score 0):

According to the W3C:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
> followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
> underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Blank value for the attribute is not valid.
In your case when you have a `false` state for `showLinks`, the value of the `id` is `blank`. This leads to an undefined value.

You can use a `className` instead of an `id`. But a better approach would be to conditionally render the nav like this:

```
<nav>
    { 
      showLinks && <ul className="nav_links" id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Resume</li>
      </ul>
    }
</nav>
```